# Objective c return type switch

Tags: objective-c, types, selector

I want to use the return type of a selector to determine how it is used in my code is there a way to differentiate the return types in objective c I'll give you an example.

```
SEL selectors[]=
{@selector(method1),
... //each method returns a different type
@selector(methodn);}  

for (SEL sel in selectors)  
    {
    switch [[self performSelector:sel]/*idk something here maybe?*/]
        {
        case int:
            //do some stuff
        ...
        case NSString *:
            //do some other stuff
        }
     }
```

Thanks in advance I couldn't find anything anywhere on this that talked about objective c

Comment: Strictly speaking, a selector doesn’t have a return type. Methods, on the other hand, do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do this via `method_copyReturnType` in objc runtime.

*however*, objc types for return and parameters are all the same (last i checked), such that the runtime will not return the type with the description "NSArray" -- it will just be the identifier for an objc type. nevertheless, that level of detail is descriptive enough for your `int` or `NSString` case, and you can use an NSObject instance's `class` or `isKindOfClass:` (etc.) instance methods to determine its type once you have a handle on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `NSMethodSignature` of the method using `-methodSignatureForSelector:`. And then you can get the return type with the `-methodReturnType` from the `NSMethodSignature` object. Don't mess with the runtime if you don't have to.